# script that can list CSS background images as HTML image tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pinterest

I use a website builder called Showit for some of my clients but I just realized that most of the images that are placed on the website are placed using CSS background-image and not in the HTML as image tags.

The problem is that the client can not use Pinterest's Pin-It button because the extension is looking for HTML image tags.

Are there any scripts that can get CSS background images and add them as HTML image tags so the Pinterest extension can see the images?

Answer (score 1):

This might work. You could also do something similar with jQuery:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(x=0; x<imgs.length; x++){
    try{
      var imgurl = imgs[x].style.backgroundImage;
      if (imgurl) {
        var newimg = document.createElement("img");
        newimg.src = imgurl;
        document.body.appendChild(newimg);
      }
    } catch(e) {}
}
```

So this iterates over the images found and extracts the `background-image` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

With pure Javascriptp this can be done with

```
<style>
#item {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    background: url('img-01.jpg') no-repeat;
}
</style>
<script>
function showImage(id, alt) {
    bg = document.getElementById(id);
    style = bg.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(bg, false), bi=style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
    document.write('<img src="' + bi + '" alt="' + alt + '">');
}
</script>
<div id="item">
    <script>showImage('item', 'This is my photo')</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow where did you get that code from? Element.currentStyle? IE6 and below... document.write? Never do it... Hidden globals? Why? Also regex will probably break on gradients. But getComputedStyle is good, at least.